# Limiting the Number of Datapoints in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

When new points are added to an **empty** HighChart chart, the number of points on the chart increases indefinitely, with the chart compressing horizontally as the X-axis range gets larger.

```
myChart.series[1].addPoint([fields.timestamp, fields.score], true, true);
```

However when more data points are added to a **non-empty** chart, the chart scrolls to the left immediately to accommodate the new data points without changing the x-axis scale. An example will be http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update. The number of datapoints displayed at any one time appears to be the original number of datapoints already on the chart when the chart was loaded.

**Question:** For both cases, how can we change/limit the number of data points on the chart (or limit the x-axis scale), such that a chart that starts off empty will increase in number of data points to `N` points before the addition of more data points cause the chart to scroll to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint) you can see a properties can be added to `series.addPoint`.
Extending [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append-and-shift/) example you can modify the button code like so:

```
// the button action
var i = 0;
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].addPoint(50 * (i % 3), true, chart.series[0].points.length > 15, true);
    i++;
});
```

I have added `chart.series[0].points.length > 15` to it. This example starts of with 12 points already on chart (so length is 11). I am going to keep adding points until there are 16 on the chart, then any new points added are appended and the last one on the left is dropped.